# What is an easy way to distribute beta builds?

Tags: distribution, beta, beta-testing

I have an app(an iphone game of about 35MB) that is in the beta testing stage.  It has gotten too big to send as an email attachment and so I need a better way to distribute it.

I don't have a good website set up so I was thinking about just distributing it with Dropbox, but then it looks like that will mean they all have to sign up for drop box first.

What is a good way to distribute a build to beta testers?

Comment: Builds of what? Without a lot more information about what you are trying to accomplish no one can help you here.

Comment: Do you need "a good website" in order to make a file publicly accessible? Why not just put the file up there and give your beta testers a URL?

Comment: You can use the public folder of dropbox and just fire out a link...doesn't require the user to have dropbox installed.  Just share the public link to the file with people.

Comment: It's a build of an iphone app(game) that's about 35MB.  I will add that too the question.                                              By "good website" I mean the only website I have right now is one for another iPhone game and it is all done with the automatic stuff the host gives not HTML so I don't know how to add that to it.  Thought I suppose I could just set up a new website to put the link on.

Comment: @Spacemoses, oh cool, I didn't know there was a public folder option for drop box, I might just use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like [TransferBigFiles.com](http://www.transferbigfiles.com) or its equivalent. You upload the package and the site sends an email with the download link. The link has an expiration date and can also be passworded.

Comment: That looks like a good way to do it.  Though, now that I see I can also use the public folder in dropbox I might use it instead.

Answer (score 1):

If it is open source then you can look into http://github.com

Closed source alternative - http://bettercodes.org

They are both a bit more involved than just mirroring your files, as they both handle version control - but that is probably worth doing in the long run for managing your code during development.